# TreeSets follow through

Tags: java

I'm trying to follow through a small program and cannot really fully understand it. Somewhere along the lines I'm going wrong in what I think it does, but I know `where =[]` If anyone could point me in the correct direction I'd be grateful.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Duplicates {

    //Here we have a main method


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    String[] words = args[0].split(" ");
    Set<String> uniques = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> duplicates = new TreeSet<String>();

    for (String s : words) {
        if (!uniques.add(s)) {
        duplicates.add(s);
        }
    }

    uniques.removeAll(duplicates);
    System.out.println("Unique words "+uniques);
    System.out.print("Duplicate words "+duplicates);
    }
```

I understand what it does ( kinda ), but I'm unsure what happens when you get a unique word. As in the loop it's saying `if (!unique.add(s))` so that will only deal with duplicats... ? then when we go inside the if statements it's dealing with `duplicates.add(s)`. So, I don't understand how the uniques are being added to the unique set ?

Comment: Did you even read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)?... If you did, u'll know that `Set`s cannot store duplicates.

Comment: Read the javadoc of Set.add() and Set.removeAll(), then execute the code step by step, on paper, with an example list of strings containing duplicates. Side note: a HashSet would be a better choice for this program.

Comment: Yeah that's the point in the program...It was an example given to us in a lecture... we're removing all the duplicates. I however cannot follow through the for/if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input is a list of String and the output is that list without duplicated ones.

in a for loop all input strings added to a Set (`uniques`) that is a collection of unique strings.

if the current string in for loop added befor to set the add method returns false.
in this case the string adds to the another set (`duplicates`).

after the loop result should be all string without the duplicated one.

now think how you can calculate all strings minus strings that duplicated 3 times?

Answer (score 1):

```
uniques.add(s))
```

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

The method returns a Boolean, true if successful and false if failed. The exclamation mark inverts the Boolean so if it returns false then ! makes it true and it can proceed to add it to the duplicate set which will fail if it already exists in the  duplicate set thus giving you a set of only unique items in the first set and dumping the duplicates into the second set but only counting the first duplicate per unique string.

The duplicate set shouldn't be a set because it will not count how many duplicates in total.

> Suppose you inputted "abc" "def" "def"

You would get 2 unique items and 1 duplicate.

> But if you inputted "abc" "abc" "abc"

You would get 1 unique item and 1 duplicate because the second time you try to insert the duplicate it will fail because a set will never let you add the same thing twice.

The intention of your example however seems to be to output words ONLY entered once in the unique set and output words entered MORE than once under the duplicate set.

change the string[] line to this

```
String[] words = new String[] { "a", "a", "b", "c" };
```

your output will be

> Unique words [b, c]
>
> Duplicate words [a]

This is because the removeAll method takes away among the unique set any item that is in the duplicate set.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot! Therefore if I use the values "John" "Joe" "John".. then it will return true for the first two since they're unique values and add it to uniques...and then the last John will return false and follow through to the other statement and be added to duplicates set?

Comment: @user3443834 Exactly, then  the removeAll method removes John from the unique set and you are left with John only in the duplicate set.

Answer (score 0):

Just take an example and walk through.

Suppose `words = { "a", "b", "b", "c"}`

Now initially `"a"` gets added to `uniques`.
Then `"b"` gets added.

When second `"b"` comes, `uniques.add(s))` returns `false` since it already contains element `"b"`. So `"b"` is added to `duplicates`.

Then `"c"` gets added to `uniques`.

Finally `uniques.removeAll(duplicates)` statement removes all elements in `uniques` that are present in `duplicates`. So you have all elements appearing only once in `uniques` and all elements repeated more than once in `duplicates`

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! but since duplicates aren't allowed, if we had in the example I had given three duplicate values e.g. A,A and A what would happen to the third A since it would return false for both?

Comment: Third time it would return false, so it tries to add to `duplicates`. But since it is already present there, it wont be added again.